# How did Natasha break her mind control?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow, black-widow-2021

Unlike Yelena, Natasha was never exposed to the red synthetic chemical agent. How then did Natasha break her programming and turn into a rogue Widow?

Comment: I seem to recall that the 'brain control' programme started after Natasha's defection.

Comment: Indeed, Nat was subject to standard brain washing techniques not the chemical method used in later years.